# Facing issue to run JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing issue to run the JavaScript file in VS code.
I am getting the output as:-

```
[Running] node "e:\n\Temporay folders of web development\vs code project\tut64.js"
node:internal/fs/utils:343
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'tut64.txt'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:582:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:450:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\n\Temporay folders of web development\vs code project\tut64.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'tut64.txt'
}

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.839 seconds
```

And in the terminal I am getting:-

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



PS E:\n\Temporay folders of web development\vs code project> node \tut64.js\
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\tut64.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)        
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I am not getting what type of these errors are and why I am getting them.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: First error looks like you're trying to open a file at the wrong path (the `.txt` file). Second one is because you're trying to run the `.js` file at the wrong path.

Comment: 2) The `.` is important... `node .\tut64.js` or remove the dot-slash entirely since it seems to be confusing you

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal you should do `node tut64.js`

And check the path of `tut64.txt` or post your code.

Comment: tut64.txt and tut64.js are in the same folder.